# Join two lists without lookup column using caml query, sharepoint online web services

Tags: web-services, join, sharepoint, caml

I have two lists:

```
list1(fields)-->City , ID

list2(fields)-->customer , ID
```

I need to join these two lists on the basis of similar `ID`, I can't use the lookup column method. How can it be achieved?

(using sharepoint online, caml query and sharepoint web services)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to use a CAML Join to join two lists, without a lookup.

You would need to query the primary list, and submit another query to retrieve items from the second list and join them in code.